# Remove ugly shadows from DatePicker in Spinner Mode

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm trying to include a DatePicker in my activity that looks like this:

[image]

but regardless of what theme I use, it looks like this with shadows on the spinners:

[image]

I've been unable to find any attributes that effect the shadow color, remove it, or anything. Is it possible to change this or do I have to write a custom view just to have some control of visuals? (Note: this is NOT a DatePickerDialog, this is a DatePicker).